# JS date format in dynamic field CF7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, date, contact-form-7

This time I have question how to convert date into dynamic field by `"m-d-Y"`.

**CF7 code**

```
<label>Date of Birth</label>                     
   [date* date-dob class:form-control placeholder id:idate "mm/dd/yyyy"]
   [dynamictext xxx id:pdfdate "date-dob format='m/d/Y'"]
```

**output result** :
The result in dynamic field is not `"m/d/Y"` there is come by default `"Y-m-d"`.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In what language/technology?

Answer (score 0):

This script will instantly read values typed into your fields and will update the full address dynamic field.

You also need to add id to your `dynamictext [dynamictext xxx id:pdfdate]`

```
<script>
var pdfdate = document.getElementById("pdfdate");
var fullDate = document.getElementById("idate");

fullDate.addEventListener("input", (e) => {

    var dates = e.target.value.split("-");
    var dateformats = ""
    if (dates.length == 3) {
       var dateformats = dates[1] + "/" + dates[2] + "/" + dates[0];
    }

    pdfdate.value = dateformats

});
</script>
```